# Crear un PDF en cake php

Tags: php, pdf, backend, cakephp

Estoy tratando de generar un PDF en cake php de backend y from de Vue.js pero no encuentro ninguna herramienta que me ayude alguien podría echarme una mano

Comment: Puedes utilizar las librerías de TCPDF (https://tcpdf.org/) y FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/). Ambas tienen bastantes ejemplos, pero tu consulta es bastante general, tal vez si pudieras por favor explicar o brindar mas contexto. Saludos.